# Fresh Wordpress install not reflecting changes on files instantly

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, server, mediatemple

I have a fresh wordpress 4.0 install on my server for a specific domain and when I make changes to any of the theme files it won't show up in the browser for a few reloads. I just add "asdf" to the theme file to test changes. I can refresh 20 times but no changes show up until like 20 seconds later.

What I have tried:

- Turned off firefox's cache.
- Turned off wordpress cache.
- Tested other domains on my server with wordpress and they work properly.
- Installed wordpress with "server installer apps"(3 times) and also with manual installation.
- I refresh with ctrl+f5
- Tried with firefox and with chrome, same results.

Its a fresh install so no plugins, no settings changes. There is no caching and my other domains work properly. No errors show up in the console.

I have no idea what the problem could be. My server company, mediatemple, said it could be my ISP, but other domains on my site work properly from the same computer/network. For some reason the problem is specific to this domain and the problem persists through all the themes.

I don't know what to do next. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. :)

Update:

- Have tried manual install of wordpress 3.9 and that does nothing.
- I added a new folder to the root and in that folder I added a file called index.html to test if this file, which is unaffected by wordpress, would show instant changes and IT DOES. **So the problem seems to be based within wordpress and specific to this domain.**

Comment: I am currently manually installing wordpress version 3.9 right now. I will let you know how that goes. I hope it fixes the problem.

Comment: ^ Update: same thing happens with wordpress 3.9...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke to Mediatemple for the 3rd time now and this guy was much more helpful and he actually solved the problem.

When you add a domain to mediatemple it automatically sets the PHP version to "FastCGI", which normally is fine, but it caused problems specifically on this one domain's wordpress install for unknown reasons. So he **switched the PHP version to "CGI (Stable)" and that fixed every problem**.

I hope this will be helpful to someone in the future. :]